# open file dialog not working in vista and 2008 environment

Tags: c#

i am using Vista . I designed MSi file through Visual Studio
2008 Setup and deployment project in which I added one custom action. In
the custom action, I am opening OpenFile dialog.
This Open File dialog is not showing mapped drive or network locations.
Can anybody help???

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the custom action running with elevation? This is a problem with UAC: elevated tokens cannot see mapped drives or network locations associated with the original, non-elevated, account.

Comment: so what can be done to make the open file dialog button to work?